# CREATE UNIQUE TOKEN(NUMERIC)

Tags: postgresql, token, sequences

I have a database where I want to generate unique tokens of six numeric characters. This tokens should be generated each time an invoice number is inserted in the `invoice_no` column. This would mean that every time I do an insert and the column `invoice_no` is not `null`, the token is generated of the numerals. I want the token to be to generate as many tokens as possible without a token being repeated at any instance. Thanks

Comment: Better suited for [dba.stackexchange.com](http://dba.stackexchange.com)

Comment: Just a heads up on your requirements.  If you say at most the token can be 6 numbers and they must be unique, you will run out of all possibilities with 999,999 inserts. Is this what you intend?

Answer (score 2):

You can create a sequence and use it to produce the tokens:

```
CREATE SEQUENCE seq_token
MINVALUE 0
MAXVALUE 999999
CYCLE
;
```

To set the current token to the next available value:

```
num_token := nextval('seq_token');
```

Your actual token has to be 6 digit long.  If you use tokens beginning with zeros (eg. 002354), than the actual token has to be a text, which you can produce like

```
text_token := lpad(num_token::text, 6, '0');
```

If the tokens have to be numeric, than change `MINVALUE` to 100000.

(The assignments are in `plpgsql`.  You can use these in a trigger or a stored procedure.)